# What is the BigQuery equivalent of SELECT * FROM (VALUES ...) AS t

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to setup a CTE with a constant table using this PosgreSQL syntax:

```
WITH rates AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
      (2017, 2018, 0.1),
      (2016, 2017, 0.1),
      (2015, 2016, 0.2),
      (2014, 2015, 0.3)
  ) AS t(init, end, rate)
)
SELECT * FROM my_bq_table as my
  JOIN rates as r ON my.year = r.init;
```

But I'm getting `Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ","` because apparently BigQuery doesn't recognize the syntax `VALUES [(tuple)]` as a `from-clause` exactly like PostgreSQL.

What is the easiest way to achieve a similar CTE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
WITH rates AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
      STRUCT<init INT64, `end` INT64, rate FLOAT64>
      (2017, 2018, 0.1),
      (2016, 2017, 0.1),
      (2015, 2016, 0.2),
      (2014, 2015, 0.3)
  ])
)
SELECT * FROM rates
```

with output

[image]